# Sort array of objects using other arrays

Tags: javascript, sorting

I create this array of objects:

```
const palette = [
  {
    color: 'Blue',
    brightness: 'Soft',
  },
  {
    color: 'Blue',
    brightness: 'Medium',
  },
  {
    color: 'Blue',
    brightness: 'Principal',
  },
  {
    color: 'Magenta',
    brightness: 'Soft',
  },
  {
    color: 'Magenta',
    brightness: 'Medium',
  },
  {
    color: 'Magenta',
    brightness: 'Principal',
  }
]
```

I want a new array with objects in this order:

```
const colorOrder = ['Blue', 'Magenta']
const brightnessOrder = ['Principal', 'Soft', 'Medium']
```

So this is the result I would like to have:

```
const colors = [
  {
    color: 'Blue',
    brightness: 'Principal',
  },
  {
    color: 'Blue',
    brightness: 'Soft',
  },
  {
    color: 'Blue',
    brightness: 'Medium',
  },
  {
    color: 'Magenta',
    brightness: 'Principal',
  }
  {
    color: 'Magenta',
    brightness: 'Soft',
  },
  {
    color: 'Magenta',
    brightness: 'Medium',
  },
]
```

I try this function:

```
function sortArrayByAnotherArray(array: any[], order: number[] | string[], key: string) {
  const newArray = array.slice(0).sort((a, b) => {
    const A = a[key]
    const B = b[key]
    return order.indexOf(A) < order.indexOf(B) ? 1 : -1
  })
  return newArray
}
```

I call it in this way:

```
const palette1 = sortArrayByAnotherArray(
  palette,
  brightnessOrder,
  'brightness'
)
const palette2 = sortArrayByAnotherArray(
  palette1,
  colorOrder,
  'color'
)

console.log('\n', palette)

console.log('\n', brightnessOrder)
console.log(palette1)

console.log('\n', colorOrder)
console.log(palette2)
```

The result is:

```
`
` [ { color: 'Blue', brightness: 'Soft' },
  { color: 'Blue', brightness: 'Medium' },
  { color: 'Blue', brightness: 'Principal' },
  { color: 'Magenta', brightness: 'Soft' },
  { color: 'Magenta', brightness: 'Medium' },
  { color: 'Magenta', brightness: 'Principal' } ]
`
` [ 'Principal', 'Soft', 'Medium' ]
[ { color: 'Blue', brightness: 'Medium' },
  { color: 'Magenta', brightness: 'Medium' },
  { color: 'Blue', brightness: 'Soft' },
  { color: 'Magenta', brightness: 'Soft' },
  { color: 'Blue', brightness: 'Principal' },
  { color: 'Magenta', brightness: 'Principal' } ]
`
` [ 'Blue', 'Magenta' ]
[ { color: 'Magenta', brightness: 'Medium' },
  { color: 'Magenta', brightness: 'Soft' },
  { color: 'Magenta', brightness: 'Principal' },
  { color: 'Blue', brightness: 'Medium' },
  { color: 'Blue', brightness: 'Soft' },
  { color: 'Blue', brightness: 'Principal' } ]
```

It's a mess, the order is not like the one in the arrays: colors are inverted and also brightness values.
Then I think that call this function twice (or more) creates problems. 
Is there a way to solve this? Exists a smarted way to do what I need?

Comment: what about unknown values in the order arrays? do you have a complete list, or should unknown items moved to top or bottom or at any other place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could chain the wanted order with [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) and the deltas of the indices.

```js
const
    palette = [{ color: 'Blue', brightness: 'Soft' }, { color: 'Blue', brightness: 'Medium' }, { color: 'Blue', brightness: 'Principal' }, { color: 'Magenta', brightness: 'Soft' }, { color: 'Magenta', brightness: 'Medium' }, { color: 'Magenta', brightness: 'Principal' }],
    colorOrder = ['Blue', 'Magenta'],
    brightnessOrder = ['Principal', 'Soft', 'Medium'];

palette.sort((a, b) => 
    colorOrder.indexOf(a.color) - colorOrder.indexOf(b.color) ||
    brightnessOrder.indexOf(a.brightness) - brightnessOrder.indexOf(b.brightness)
);

console.log(palette);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

An approach to sort a copy with a function and given order arrays.

```js
function sortArrayByAnotherArrays(data, orders) {
    const
        getObject = array => array.reduce((r, k, i) => (r[k] = i + 1, r), {}),
        objects = orders.map(([k, a]) => [k, getObject(a)]);

    return data
        .slice()
        .sort((a, b) => {
            var v;
            objects.some(([k, o]) => v = o[a[k]] - o[b[k]]);
            return v;
        });
}

const
    palette = [{ color: 'Blue', brightness: 'Soft' }, { color: 'Blue', brightness: 'Medium' }, { color: 'Blue', brightness: 'Principal' }, { color: 'Magenta', brightness: 'Soft' }, { color: 'Magenta', brightness: 'Medium' }, { color: 'Magenta', brightness: 'Principal' }],
    colorOrder = ['Blue', 'Magenta'],
    brightnessOrder = ['Principal', 'Soft', 'Medium'],
    ordered = sortArrayByAnotherArrays(
        palette,
        [
            ['color', colorOrder],           // [key, values in order]
            ['brightness', brightnessOrder]
        ]
    );

console.log(ordered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks! I try to generalize this process creating this function: 

    ```function sortBy(datasetToSort: any[], orders: {order: string[] | number[], key: string}[]) {
      const datasetToSortCloned = datasetToSort.slice(0)
      const result = datasetToSortCloned.sort((a, b) => {
        const something = orders.map((o, i) => {
          const {order, key} = o
          return order.indexOf(a['key']) - order.indexOf(b['key'])
        })
        // something[0] || something[1] || ...
      })
      return result
    }```

But how can I do `something[0] || something[1] || ...`?

Comment: Thanks but it seems not to work. Look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-rgb-4y2tn

Comment: the key name of the sort must match the given name in the object. instead of `color`, you need `colorName`, otherwise the property can not be addressed properly.

Answer (score 0):

If the result is inverted, you can try to invert the sort condition

```
return order.indexOf(A) > order.indexOf(B) ? 1 : -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort by the difference in index of each objects' color in the `colorOrder`, and alternate with the difference in index of each objects' brightness in the `brightnessOrder`.

Keep in mind that `.sort` sorts in place - `sorted` is the same object as `palette`. If you don't want to mutate the original array, clone it first.

```js
const palette=[{color:"Blue",brightness:"Soft"},{color:"Blue",brightness:"Medium"},{color:"Blue",brightness:"Principal"},{color:"Magenta",brightness:"Soft"},{color:"Magenta",brightness:"Medium"},{color:"Magenta",brightness:"Principal"}];

const colorOrder = ['Blue', 'Magenta'];
const brightnessOrder = ['Principal', 'Soft', 'Medium'];

const sorted = palette.sort((a, b) => (
  colorOrder.indexOf(a.color) - colorOrder.indexOf(b.color) ||
  brightnessOrder.indexOf(a.brightness) - brightnessOrder.indexOf(a.brightness)
));
console.log(sorted);
```