# sort array object using other array

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

not able to sort array object according to given array
can you please help me out!!

[reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57323336/11231375)

```
const data = [ {
    parent_email: 'testuser@mailinator.com',
    childSurName: null,
    childFirstName: null,
    id: 22},
{
    parent_email: 'p20@mailinator.com',
    childSurName: null,
    childFirstName: 'Sachidanand',
    id: 31},
{
    parent_email: 'aa@aa.aaa',
    childSurName: null,
    childFirstName: null,
    id: 26}];

const order = [ 31,26 ];

const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => (
     order.indexOf(a.id)  - order.indexOf(b.id)
));

console.log(sorted)
```

I need sorted result like my second array are and then after other data :

```
 [ {
    parent_email: 'p20@mailinator.com',
    childSurName: null,
    childFirstName: 'Sachidanand',
    id: 31},
 {
    parent_email: 'aa@aa.aaa',
    childSurName: null,
    childFirstName: null,
    id: 26}
{
    parent_email: 'testuser@mailinator.com',
    childSurName: null,
    childFirstName: null,
    id: 22},
];
```

but i am getting below result not getting proper sorted data:

```
[{
    parent_email:"testuser@mailinator.com",
    childSurName:null,
    childFirstName:null,
    id:22
 },
 {
    parent_email:"p20@mailinator.com",
    childSurName:null,
    childFirstName:"Sachidanand",
    id:31
 },
 {
    parent_email:"aa@aa.aaa",
    childSurName:null,
    childFirstName:null,
    id:26
 }]
```

Comment: `"22" !== 22` so your `indexOf` doesn't find the IDs

Comment: @VLAZ ok let me edit question then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Map` and `place values along with priority` inside Map and then sort,

**Note:-** Also don't forget to keep the search value and key of same type

```js
const data = [{parent_email: 'testuser@mailinator.com',childSurName: null,childFirstName: null,id: 22},{parent_email: 'p20@mailinator.com',childSurName: null,childFirstName: 'Sachidanand',id: 31},{parent_email: 'aa@aa.aaa',childSurName: null,childFirstName: null,id: 26}];

const order = ['31', '22'];
const mapper = new Map(order.map((v, i) => [parseInt(v), i + 1]))

const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => (
  (mapper.get(a.id) || Infinity) - (mapper.get(b.id) || Infinity)
));

console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => order.indexOf(a.id.toString()) - order.indexOf(b.id.toString()) );
```

`id` must be converted `toString`.

Alternatively, change

```
 const order = [ '31','22' ];
```

to

```
 const order = [ 31,22 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of id `22`. It does not exist in `order` array and `indexOf` function return `-1` for this id. It means the `top priority`, so it appears in the first place of result array.
You should handle ids that do not exist in the `order` array.
For example (for sorting) you can do as below:

```
const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => {
    let aindex = order.indexOf(a.id);
    let bindex = order.indexOf(b.id);
    if(aindex === -1) return 1;
    if(bindex === -1) return -1;
    return aindex  - bindex;
});
```